# vuetify v-select show long strings

Tags: string, vuetify.js, long-integer, v-select

I'm making a form which includes v-select control with long string items such as

- long string item to display Head
- long string item to display Hands

And so on.

The v-select control will be display by using cellphones so the users should read each item, instead the following

- long string ítem...
- long string ítem...

Is there an option to display the complete item text into the list items?

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/Selobu/pen/eYpMJxM)

```
properties: {
    slotProps: {
      type: "string",
      title: "Custom enums",
      enum: [
        'long string item to display in devices with small screens and Head',
        'long string item to display in devices with small screens and Hands',
        'long string item to display in devices with small screens and Eyes',
        'long string item to display in devices with small screens and Stomach',],
    },
    }
```

Here are some screen captures:

[image: Displayed when selected]

[image: Displayed later]

Comment: Can you please explain with an example, that what you are trying to achieve, Also if you can create a codepen for the above issue. That would be really helpful to solve your issue faster

Answer (score 0):

Directly give items inside slot. this will remove text truncation.

```
<v-select
  v-model="select"
  :items="items"
  label="Select"
  >
  <template v-slot:item="slotProps">
    {{slotProps.item}}
  </template>
</v-select>

...
...
data: {
  select: null,
  items: [
    'long string item to display Head',
    'long string item to display Hands',
    'long string item to display Eyes',
    'long string item to display Stomach',
   ],
}
```

[image]